# Why does CSS rotate randomly switches direction after multiple turns on Safari and how can I prevent this?

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, css-transforms

I needed to create a card element that always flips in the same direction when clicked and the following snippet does exactly what I want but only when using Chrome and Firefox. When viewing the snippet on Safari both on iOS and MacOS, one encounters a weird issue where after approximately 20 clicks, the card flips randomly back and forth and becomes unpredictable as shown in the attached screen record.

Is this a known issue and is there anything to prevent this from happening?

```js
let rot = 0;
function flip() {
    rot++;
    const flipContent = document.getElementById("flip").querySelector(".flip-content");
    flipContent.style.transform = `rotateX(${rot * 0.5}turn)`;
    flipContent.style.boxShadow = (rot % 2 === 0) ? `20px 20px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4)` : `20px -20px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4)`;
}
```

```css
html, body {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.flip-card {
    width: 70vmin;
    height: 70vmin;
    margin: auto;
    background: transparent;
    perspective: 1000px;
    transition: scale 0.3s;
    scale: 90%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.flip-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    box-shadow: 20px 20px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
.front-face, .back-face {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.front-face {
    background-color: blue;
}
.back-face {
    background-color: red;
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
.flip-card:hover {
    scale: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="flip" class="flip-card" onclick="flip()">
    <div class="flip-content">
        <div class="front-face"></div>
        <div class="back-face"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

[A screen record made on Safari on MacOS that demonstrates the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyUlk.gif)

Comment: https://bugs.webkit.org/ (Note that even with the Web Animations API they do fail: https://jsfiddle.net/hfm423o6/

Comment: @Kaiido Interesting, I would have thought this would fix it. So this is simply a bug in webkit?

Answer (score -1):

Add the prefix vendor `-webkit-` for Safari in front of `backface-visibility` property:

```css
.front-face, .back-face {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve my issue